# First Non-Repeating Character In Stream in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here's my original code

```
from collections import OrderedDict
class Solution:
  def __init__(self):
    # Initialize the class.
    self.dic = OrderedDict()

  def read(self, ch):
    # Implement this method here.
    if ch in self.dic:
      self.dic[ch] += 1
    else:
      self.dic[ch] = 1
    self.dic = dict(sorted(self.dic.items(), key=lambda item: item[1]))

  def first_non_repeat(self):
    # Implement this method here.
    if list(self.dic.values())[0] != 1 or not self.dic:
      return None
    else:
      return list(self.dic.keys())[0]
```

I'd like to find the first non-repeating character in O(1) time at any moment when calling the method, so I use the OrderedDict to trace the character in the stream, However, when the stream are

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'd', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'e']
```

the output should be

```
['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'd', None, None, 'e']
```

However, Mine is

```
['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'c', None, None, None, None]
```

Could anyone help me to figure out where I'm wrong? Thanks

Comment: I don't get what do you mean for O(1) time... You can't determine the answer in O(1). I am also not too sure about what your two functions are supposed to do. Can you explain a bit more? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Is this something you are looking for ?

```
lst=['a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'd', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'e']
d={x : lst.count(x) for x in lst}
min(d,key=d.get)
```

This will return e

Comment: Sorry, maybe it is not be explained clearly. The input is a stream which means it will be read one by one, meanwhile, we have to update or trace the first non-repeating character when a new character come in. It's not a list input for one time